# Press a button that holds geo-location details from different activity and display it on MapView?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I have a mapView class and a StoreFinder class. I want to be able to press a button that is in my AlertDialog, which holds geo-point values longitude and latitude. I want it to display the position of the longitude and latitude values in my MapView.

Simple:

Press button with longitude and latitude IN ALERTDIALOG -> MapView display position.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you for your ample time.

CODE:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.storefinder_bars);

    sirius();
}

public void sirius() {
    ImageButton hoursButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    ImageButton addressButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.address);
    //ImageButton phoneButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.phone);


    final AlertDialog.Builder siriushours = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    hoursButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            siriushours.setTitle("Opening Hours");
            siriushours.setMessage(

                       "\n---Monday---\n" +        "CLOSED" 
                     + "\n\n---Tuesday---\n" +     "CLOSED" 
                     + "\n\n---Wednesday---\n" +   "22:00 - 3:00" 
                     + "\n\n---Thursday---\n" +    "CLOSED" 
                     + "\n\n---Friday---\n" +      "22:00 - 3:00"
                     + "\n\n---Saturday---\n" +    "22:00 - 3:00"
                     + "\n\n---Sunday---\n" +      "CLOSED");

            siriushours.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    });

            siriushours.show();
        }
    });

    //ADDRESS
    final AlertDialog.Builder siriusadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    addressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            siriusadd.setTitle("Address");
            siriusadd.setMessage(

                    "33 Belvoir Street, Leicester , LE1 6SL");



            siriusadd.setPositiveButton("Show On Map",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {




                        }

                    });

            siriusadd.setNegativeButton("Route",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+52.63274+","+-1.13145));
                                    startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    });


            siriusadd.show();
        }
    });


}
```

I want to make the POSITIVE BUTTON LOCATED HERE: "siriusadd.setPositiveButton("Show On Map", " to allow me to jump from the AlertDialog to my MapView geo-cordinate. If not, I have balloon itemized layout, I have markers in place. I would prefer if they would jump to that instead. However, geo-points would do.

Cheers for all the assistance.

Comment: Doesn't sound complicated. Just paste your code here. So it will become clear, what the actual problem is.

Comment: code updated in main body. Check it out mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MapController` to animate to desired geopoint.
Instantiate `MapController` for your `MapView`:

```
private MapController mc;
mc = mapView.getController();
```

After initialization of dialog set `onClickListener` for button (here is example for positive button:

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.photo), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
                mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
            }

        });
```

Comment: No, this does not work. I have it extended to Activity. I need it extended to Activity for the AlertDialog to work.

Comment: Do you want to go to that position or display some marker on that position?

Comment: no, that doesn't work either because this is if it is from the SAME Activity. I need it to be able todo it from ANOTHER activity.

Comment: Check out the putExtra / get...Extra mechanism in my answer. These methods target cross activity data exchange.

Comment: Try to pass geopoint by `SharedPreferences` and load geopoint on starting `MapActivity`.

Comment: That is actually a good suggestion. I will try that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use putExtra in calling an intent:

```
siriusadd.setPositiveButton("Show On Map",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MyMapActivity.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("id", anId);
                        // add any additional informations with other key values 
                        // (latitude or longitude)
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                    }

                });
```

Get these information in your map activity's onResume method into your map activity and set up your map view appropriately:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getStringExtra("id") == null) {
        // your map logic goes here
    }

}
```